# Need to upgrade my dedicated server. Is this a good deal?

Tags: dedicated-server

I'm looking to upgrade to a better dedicated server at my host LiquidWeb and would like some advice.

I currently have a Pentium 4 3GHZ Hyperthreaded, 2GB RAM, and 2 120GB Hard Drives and have been paying $227/month (I've actually been overpaying, since they have lowered their prices since I first signed up with them, but never pro-rated me..)

My current server is very overloaded. What I really need is more RAM, but apparently I need a processor upgrade to add more ram, so..

They said that I can upgrade to the following setup for $270 a month:

»   Processor: Intel i5-750 Quad Core
»   RAM: 4GB DDR SDRAM
»   HD1: SATA Drive (7,200 rpm) (+250 GB 7200 RPM SATA hard drive)
»   HD2: SATA Backup Drive (+250 GB SATA (7,200 rpm))
»   GUARD: No Remote Backup Needed
»   OS: Windows Server (+Windows 2008 Standard 64-bit) (+No Anti-Virus) (+No MSSQL Software Required.)
»   Bandwidth: 6000GB Monthly Transfer (3000 in + 3000 out) (+100M uplink port)
»   ControlPanel: cPanel/ Web Host Manager - Fully Managed (+ServerSecure) (+Fantastico)
»   SetupFee: No setup fee
»   Monthly Fee: $270.00 /mon

Is this a fairly decent server upgrade for the price?

Comment: Product recommendations questions, including specification/price market research, are off-topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), and on [StackExchange generally](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/qa).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a dedicated server?

Because there are some really good deals on VPS's around, and personally I dont know if having a physical machine vs virtual would matter. Places like [Slice-host](http://www.slicehost.com) [linode](http://www.linode.com) or [gandi.net](http://www.gandi.net) are great, and really very cheap. I've only used gandi.net, but i've heard good things about the others. Full root access, choice of operating systems etc.

Comment: I definitely need a dedicated server, as I run a fairly high traffic web site with lots of database reads/writes.

Comment: I dont really understand why you need a dedicated server over a bunch of virtual servers. I guess if you are scaling vertically instead of horizontally. But the VPS plans have pretty good SLA's etc on them. And you could easily get quite a few separate virtual images for the amount your paying.

Comment: And - if you have a ton of database reads and writes, why do you get a crappy low end storage subsystemt hat will be slow?